# node stream concats chunks before running

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a tranfrom stream that is writing not pushing to the another stream because the stream changes what it writes to.If I write to same stream multiple times in a row it,before it emits the data event, concats them together.

the router that gets input and outputs that to the correct stream. This uses the stdio[3] to pipe to and stdio[4] to get input from the child process.

```
Controller.prototype._transform = function(chunk,enc,done)
{
let push = this.push.bind(this);
try
{
    const input = JSON.parse(chunk.toString());

    const task = nextTask(input.id);
    if(task != null)
    {
        const pipe = getPipe(task.pipe);
        let output = {};

        if(!hasExpectedFields(task))
            throw {err:stacks[input.id].name+ ' does not have expected fields passed to it for '+pipe.name,action:input.id};

        if(!hasRequiredFields(task))
            throw {err:stacks[input.id].name+ ' does not have required fields for '+pipe.name,action:input.id};
        else
            output = attachRequired(input,task,pipe);

        (pipe.storable) ? output.store = task.store: output.store = null;
        console.log();
        if(pipe.started)
        {
            pipe.write(JSON.stringify(output))
        }
        else
        {
            pipe.startProcess();
            pipe.write(JSON.stringify(output));
        }
        done();
    }
    else
    {
        const taskName = stacks[input.id].name;
        console.log("task "+taskName+" is complete");
        done();
    }
}catch(e)
{
    if(e.err)
        console.log(e.err);
    else
        console.log(e);
    done();
}
```

};

one of the many pipes that the can be piped to. Use net socket to get piped from parent process. Uses fs write stream to pipe to parent.

```
Globber.prototype._transform = function(chunk,enc,done)
{
   let push = this.push.bind(this);
   try
   {
       task = JSON.parse(chunk.toString());
       globby(task.regex).then(paths=>
          {
              task.input = paths;
              task.regex = null;
              (task.store) ? task[task.store] = task.input:null;
              push(JSON.stringify(task));
            done();
        }).catch(x => console.log(x))
}catch(e)
{
    console.log(e);
}
};
```

Comment: Can you create some small example, it seems hard to debug your issue from the code you've provided.

Comment: *"If I write to same stream multiple times in a row it,before it emits the data event, concats them together."* Yep, that’s how streams work. Use Node’s object IPC or something if you don’t want to deal with that.

Comment: @drinchev added some more code